# how to create pkcs11 library in windows

Tags: cryptography, cryptoapi, pkcs#11

I have been using the library pkcs11Interop and I would like to know how could I create a pkcs11 library dll. I've been searching a lot but I didnt understand it, I want to create a pkcs11 library because i would like to specify where are stored my certificates and define how import and export them.

I found the Cryptographic Provider Development Kit but i didnt found a sample of what i want.

What i need to create my own pkcs11 library dll?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your use case?

Comment: i would like to create a pkcs11 library that import and export keys from my own architecture

Answer (score 4):

> What do I need to create my own PKCS#11 library dll?

Good knowledge of [PKCS#11 specifications](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS) and a basic C/C++ skills.

Take a look at [PKCS11-MOCK](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/pkcs11-mock) if you are not sure how to setup your project or where to start. It is a dummy library implementing PKCS#11 API and it currently builds on Windows, Linux, OSX, Android and iOS. We are using it for an automated testing of [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop) wrapper and GnuTLS project uses it for [custom object attributes](https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/commit/7b898af19606c7a0c331f0768e3f2b2f8c53c9bb) testing.

Comment: what is pkcs11 mock? A sample of pkcs11 library?

Comment: @user3789330 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

To create a PKCS#11 library you just need to implement the PKCS#11 interfaces (which are part of the standard) and compile a PKCS#11 DLL. Microsoft had to take a different course and defined their own API, the CSP API. So you won't find PKCS#11 support in the CSP devkit.

Sometimes PKCS#11 libraries are used as implementation for Windows CSP's. The CSP is then used for supporting Windows and the PKCS#11 library for everything else.

Comment: can you provide me a sample, please?